# How to see if the convergence is uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

I have the following : $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx^3} \quad n=1,2,\dots \quad$ and $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) ,$

and I have done the following :  $$|f_n(x) -f(x)| = \biggl|\frac{nx}{1+nx^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}\biggr| = \biggl|\frac{1}{x^2(1+nx^3)}\biggr |$$ where $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is the convergence of the series of the function. Now I know that $\Bigl|\frac{1}{x^2(1+nx^3)}\Bigr|< \epsilon$ but now I don't know how to choose $N$ in order to fully prove that it is uniformly convergent or not. Can somebody help me proceed with the proof?

Comment: Is the domain equal to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: You can easily see that the closer $x$ is to $0$, the larger you need $n$. So it's definitely not uniformly convergent

Comment: the question is to show it first on $(0,1) \quad$and then on $ (1,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The $f_n$'s are bounded on $(0,\infty).$ If the convergence were uniform there, then $f$ would be bounded there.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\langle 0,1\rangle$. For $\varepsilon = 1$ there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
$$n \ge n_0 \implies |f(x)-f_n(x)| < 1.$$

Now take $n := n_0 + 1$ and consider
$$\left|f\left(\frac1n\right) - f_n\left(\frac1n\right)\right| = n^2 - \frac1{1+\frac1{n^2}} \ge n^2-1 \ge n_0^2 \ge 1$$
which is a contradiction. This implies that the convergence is not uniform on $\langle 0,1\rangle$.